# List Top Items Based on UserVotes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table (in MySQL) that stores votes. The structure is like this:

```
id INT(11)
post_id INT(11)
vote_value INT(11)
created DATETIME
```

Now, `vote_value` can be any integer, e.g. 12, -17 for a post. The ***resulting vote*** will be `12 + (-17) = -5` for the post. What I am trying to achieve is to sort posts by this resulting votes. Is that possible? If so, help is much appreciated.

**NOTE** I am able to get most voted items by

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(post_id) AS Count FROM my_table GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY Count DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

This gives me top 5 *most voted* posts. i.e. it selects those posts with most number of occurrences. But I am trying to sort these by **resulting votes**. Hope that sounds clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT post_id, SUM(post_id) AS Votes FROM my_table GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY Votes DESC LIMIT 0,5

I'm not a mysql user so the sum function my be wrong.

Comment: I assume you meant `SELECT post_id, SUM(vote_value) AS Votes FROM my_table GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY Votes DESC LIMIT 0,5` And that worked perfectly! Thanks!